# Onclick Delete not stopping before pressing Okay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an onclick on a delete call

```
"<a href='" + Url.Action("Delete", "OBProfile", new { id = "#= ProfileID#" })
 + "' title='Delete' id='deleteButton' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm 
deleteButton' onclick='return confirm_delete(#= ProfileID#)'>Delete</a>"
```

and this is the script that it runs

```
function confirm_delete() {
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            closeOnConfirm: false
        },
        function () {
            swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
        });
    };
```

The issue is that it doesn't stop and wait for the Delete button to be pressed. it calls the script, the box pops up, it deletes the record, and refreshes the page.  I need it to process when I click the confirm button.  This is done using [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

Comment: jsfiddle  or something ?

Comment: the part "function () {
            swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");
        })" should be its own function, and it should be called on the submit call. Also a jsfiddle would help :)

Comment: You should move the actual deleting part `swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted!", "success");`  into a new function and call it once the user has pressed the confirm button.

Comment: What does `Url.Action("Delete", "OBProfile", new { id = "#= ProfileID#" })` do? Generates a URL?

Comment: Yea it generates a delete url.

Comment: And what is `#= ProfileID#` in the function param? you don't seem to use it in your function!

Comment: the profileID from the user in the table. Makes the url look like this /OBProfile/Delete/92

Answer (score 0):

So, you anyway have to use `jQuery` for the `swal` to work. Therefore, do not use inline event handler like you did (`onclick='return confirm_delete...`). Use event binding the jQuery way, prevent the default behaviour, when delete is confirmed, set the location to go to the link URL as below.

```js
$("#deleteButton").on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var _this = this;
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
            location.href = _this.href;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<a href='http://www.aol.com' title='Delete' id='deleteButton' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm 
deleteButton'>Delete</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to stop the delete call. It still processes the delete on click.

Comment: It doesn't in the example I gave, at least.